# How do i get days in a month under one column and different months displayed in different column

Tags: sql, pivot

```
id     date
1      5/10/2019
2      5/10/2019
3      6/11/2019
4      6/12/2019
5      5/12/2019
6      6/11/2019
7      5/12/2019
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
day      oct      nov      dec 
5        2        0        2
6        0        2        1
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: what is your dbms name

Answer (score 0):

This following script will work for **MSSQL** -

```
SELECT DATEPART(DD,date) Day,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Oct,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Nov,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Dec
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATEPART(DD,date)
```

**For Other Databases**, You just need to use appropriate DATEPART and MONTH function to fine Day and Month from your date value.

Answer (score 0):

When working with dates, you should be very careful about years and months.  You can implement your code using `pivot` (if your database supports it) or conditional aggregation . . . but you should also be careful about filtering:

```
select extract(day from date),
       sum(case when extract(month from date) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as oct,
       sum(case when extract(month from date) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as nov,
       sum(case when extract(month from date) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as dec
from t
where date >= '2019-10-01' and date < '2020-01-01'
group by extract(day from date)
order by extract(day from date);
```

Your question doesn't have a database tag.  Date functions are notoriously database-dependent, so the exact function may differ in your database.